# Which hoare-triples is correct?

Tags: logic, hoare-logic

Lets say there is a method that takes two arguments balance and price, that only does the following:

```
if(price < balance) {
    balance = balance - price;
}
```

I feel like there are two possible ways to write this in a hoare-triple:

```
(| price=p0 ^ balance = b0 |) buy (| ((p0 < balance) => balance = b0 - p0) v ((p0 >= balance) => balance = b0) |)
```

or

```
(| price=p0 ^ balance = b0 |) buy (| ((p0 < balance) ^ (balance = b0-p0)) v ((p0 >= balance) ^ (balance = b0))
```

( => is implication)
What I'm wondering is which one is correct? Or are both correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I intended for this to be a comment, but I don't have the reputation to comment. 

The two hoare-triples certainly aren't equivalent. If p0 >= balance, the right side of the first triple evaluates to true, while the right side of the second triple evaluates to false. I'm at work, and can't work out which is the correct hoare-triple right now, but I'm sure someone more qualified than me will answer before I've finished at work.</s>

If we let P := p0 < balance, Q := balance = b0 - p0, and R := balance = b0, we can represent the right sides of your equations with (P => Q) v (-P => R) and (P ^ Q) v (-P ^ R), and create the following truth table.

+---+---+---+----------------------------+------------------------+
| .P | Q | .R | (P => Q) v (-P => R) | (P ^ Q) v (-P ^ R) |
+---+---+---+----------------------------+------------------------+
| .T | .T | .T | . . . . . . . . T . . . . . . . . | . . . . . . .T . . . . . . . |
| .T | .T | .F | . . . . . . . . T . . . . . . . . | . . . . . . .T . . . . . . . |
| .T | .F | .T | . . . . . . . . T . . . . . .  . . | . . . . . . .F . . . . . . . |
| .T | .F | .F | . . . . . . . . T . . . . . .  . . | . . . . . . .F . . . . . . . |
| .F | .T | .T | . . . . . . . . T . . . . . .  . . | . . . . . . .T . . . . . . . |
| .F | .T | .F | . . . . . . . . T . . . . . .  . . | . . . . . . .F . . . . . . . |
| .F | .F | .T | . . . . . . . . T . . . . . .  . . | . . . . . . .T . . . . . . . |
| .F | .F | .F | . . . . . . . . T . . . . . .  . . | . . . . . . .F . . . . . . . |
+---+---+---+----------------------------+------------------------+

This shows that the two equations are not equivalent. 
I would guess that the correct value for the right side would be  (P => Q) ^ (-P => R), because both statements must hold. I'm new to hoare-logic, and someone more knowledgeable can probably correct me.

Comment: Are you sure? I've believe they both evaluate to true, I think I missed some parenthesis.

Comment: Let P := p0 < balance, Q := balance = b0 - p0, R := balance = b0
Then, ((p0 < balance) => balance = b0 - p0) v ((p0 >= balance) => balance = b0) becomes (P => Q) v (P => R).
Also, ((p0 < balance) ^ (balance = b0-p0)) v ((p0 >= balance) ^ (balance = b0)) becomes (P ^ Q) v (P ^ R).
So we have (P => Q) v (P => R)   =?=  (P ^ Q) v (P ^ R). If P = False, the left side becomes True, and the right side becomes False.

Comment: You use P for both p0 < balance and p0 >= balance

Comment: You're right, my mistake. The first equation would become (P => Q) v (-P => R), and the second equation would become (P ^ Q) v (-P ^ R)

Comment: Does that mean you can use both hoare-triples?

Comment: I don't think so. I just scratched out a truth table that shows they aren't equivalent, but I'm not familiar with how to replicate it here, and I want to double check my work. I'll upload my results here after work when I can look up how to insert a table here. I think the second equation is the one you want though.